# I am trying to run a query in sql where I change the fields to lowercase to make it consistent and sum the differetn fields

Tags: mysql, sql, databricks

I have field evar4 which has site searches, the text is in different cases which is leading to two different rows for the same word searched,
e.g.

```
evar4  searches
games   3236
Games    564
```

I want to convert all evar4 to lowercase field and show a single value for all same terms that is,

```
e.g.
evar4  searches
games   3800
```

I have converted the fields to lower case but I am not sure how to sum those in the sql query and show only one row for the same word.

```
Select lcase(evar4), count (evar4) as searches from adobe_hits
where (date(date_time) between '2019-01-01' and '2019-01-31')
and post_prop46 like ('www:')
and exclude_hit like '0'
and hit_source not in (5,7,8,9)
group by evar4
order by searches desc;

sample result: 

Original Result:
evar4                 searches
games                   3236
recently played games   1326
mahjongg solitaire  633
Games                   564

Result after lcase: 
lcase(evar4)            searches
games                   3236
recently played games   1326
mahjongg solitaire  633
games                   564

desired result: 
lcase(evar4)            searches
games                   3800
recently played games   1326
mahjongg solitaire  633
```

Comment: SQL tables have _columns_, not fields.

Comment: You need to GROUP BY the lcase value too.

Comment: Maybe use a case insensitive collation instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to group by the lowercase version of the field.

```
Select lcase(evar4), count (evar4) as searches from adobe_hits
where (date(date_time) between '2019-01-01' and '2019-01-31')
and post_prop46 like ('www:')
and exclude_hit like '0'
and hit_source not in (5,7,8,9)
group by lcase(evar4)
order by searches desc;
```

If you assign an alias to the expression, you can group by that.

```
Select lcase(evar4) as l_evar4, count (evar4) as searches from adobe_hits
where (date(date_time) between '2019-01-01' and '2019-01-31')
and post_prop46 like ('www:')
and exclude_hit like '0'
and hit_source not in (5,7,8,9)
group by l_evar4
order by searches desc;
```

Another solution that avoids having to do this in the first place is to declare the column to use case-insensitive collation. Then all comparisons, including grouping, will ignore case.